# How to select the table with less columns in a database with Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a large database with a lot of tables and I want to know if I can select the table that have less columns of them. How can I do that? Is there some info in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`?

Comment: Yes, just call COUNT() while filtering by table name and order the results.

Comment: And what should I count?

Comment: You count the number of columns in each table, i.e. the number of records in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` that share the same `TABLE_SCHEMA` and `TABLE_NAME` values.

Comment: What do you mean by `I want to know if I can select the table that have less columns of them`? Do you mean you want to know a list of tables that you have select permissions on? Or do you want to find out tables that has a certain number of columns? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Are you looking for differences between 2 schemas?

Comment: @abhi no, tha fact is that my database has hundreds of tables from different apps (horrible design I know) and I want to check which of them has less columns

Comment: @YerkoPalma do you want to know what single table has the least number of columns?  If so, what if several tables have the same number of columns?  Or do you want a list of all tables ordered by the count of columns ascending?  Orrrrr, do you want to find out the lowest distinct column count, and then return a list of all tables with that column count?  The question is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: Define:   "which of them has less columns".   it is vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like the other answers gave you plenty of info to help you answer your own questions with a little effort, but you don't seem satisfied, so maybe this helps.

If this isn't what you're looking for, you really need to edit your question so we can understand exactly what type of result you want.

This returns a single record for the table with the least number of columns.  You can filter this down further by schema or whatever to fit your needs.

```
  SELECT TOP 1 
    tbl.TABLE_CATALOG, 
    tbl.TABLE_SCHEMA, 
    tbl.TABLE_NAME, 
    COUNT(col.ordinal_position)
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES tbl
  JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS col
  ON tbl.TABLE_CATALOG = col.TABLE_CATALOG
  AND tbl.TABLE_NAME = col.TABLE_NAME
  AND tbl.TABLE_SCHEMA = col.TABLE_SCHEMA
  WHERE tbl.table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
  GROUP BY tbl.TABLE_CATALOG, tbl.TABLE_SCHEMA, tbl.TABLE_NAME
  ORDER BY COUNT(col.ORDINAL_POSITION)
```

But what if there's a bunch of tables with only a single column?  What to return?  You can use TSQL and find the count of columns for the table with the least number of columns, and then select all tables with that count of columns.

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE @minColumnCount INT

  --This will find the count of columns for the table with the least number of columns
  SELECT TOP 1 @minColumnCount = COUNT(col.ordinal_position)
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES tbl
  JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS col
  ON tbl.TABLE_CATALOG = col.TABLE_CATALOG
  AND tbl.TABLE_NAME = col.TABLE_NAME
  AND tbl.TABLE_SCHEMA = col.TABLE_SCHEMA
  WHERE tbl.table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
  GROUP BY tbl.TABLE_CATALOG, tbl.TABLE_SCHEMA, tbl.TABLE_NAME
  ORDER BY COUNT(col.ORDINAL_POSITION)

  --This will give you a list of tables that have exactly @minColumnCount columns
  SELECT tbl.TABLE_CATALOG, tbl.TABLE_SCHEMA, tbl.TABLE_NAME, COUNT(col.ORDINAL_POSITION)
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES tbl
  JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS col
  ON tbl.TABLE_CATALOG = col.TABLE_CATALOG
  AND tbl.TABLE_NAME = col.TABLE_NAME
  AND tbl.TABLE_SCHEMA = col.TABLE_SCHEMA
  WHERE tbl.table_type = 'BASE TABLE'  
  GROUP BY tbl.TABLE_CATALOG, tbl.TABLE_SCHEMA, tbl.TABLE_NAME
  HAVING COUNT(col.ORDINAL_POSITION) = @minColumnCount

END
```

Comment: This is like what I want. Unfortunately, I have Sql Server 2000, and `Sys.tables` and `Sys.columns` are not recognized. Can I replace them with `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` and `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`?

Comment: I updated the answer to reference INFORMATION_SCHEMA instead of SYS tables

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the list of tables and the count of columns for each table

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, 
       COUNT(COLUMN_NAME)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS col INNER JOIN 
     sys.objects obj
ON obj.name = col.TABLE_NAME
WHERE obj.type = N'U'
GROUP BY col.TABLE_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

List columns having a certain amount of columns:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COUNT(*) AS NUMCOLS
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YourTableName' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='YourSchemaName'
HAVING COUNT(NUMCOLS) > x
```

Comment: And what should I do to _loop_ through all tables with this query? because I want to get the table with less columns compared to the rest of the tables

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = N'YourSchema'
    AND TABLE_NAME = N'YourTable'
```

Detailed article: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/07/20/sql-server-information_schema-columns-and-value-character-maximum-length-1/

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I think this will return the number of columns for a certain table, so if I want the table with less columns I will have to compare all of them, that means run this query for every table... and I have hundreds of tables

Comment: Well this is just guidelines. You know where to look at. It's not that hard to figure out what needs to be done next.

Comment: That means this is not answering what I asked

Comment: You don't have to mark it ad correct answer, of course. And one of your questions was if there's some info in information schema. My answer tells that.